# (De)serializing specific subclass without using [ProtoInclude]

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I'm considering migrating current WCF-based based application to protobuf-net.Grpc. It seems to be doable, however I was not able to make protobuf-net serialize properties of (DTO classes) base class without including all derived classes with [ProtoInclude] attribute.

Simplified class hierarchy:

```
[DataContract]
public abstract class DtoBase 
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public int Id { get;set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    public int Version { get;set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 3)]
    public EditState EditState { get;set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class PersonDto : DtoBase
{ 
    [DataMember(Order=4)]
    public string FirstName { get;set; }
    [DataMember(Order=5)]
    public string LastName { get;set; }
}
```

I have investigated related questions and it all boils down to the fact that specific type should be known during deserialization - or there should be a way to determine it. Our service methods already know the specific subclass to use, e.g. we have methods like

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IPersonService 
{
    [OperationContract]
    ScalarResult<PersonDto> GetById(personId);
}
```

DataContractSerializer can do that - deserialize base class properties, when specific subclass is already known. It needs hints (known types) when you deserialize subclass having base class signature, like returning PersonDto instead of DtoBase. But when specific subclass is known, known types are not needed and everything just works.

So the question is how to do the same with protobuf-net? And if it's not possible, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Protobuf-net, like any library, makes certain assumptions and compromises. If it wants to support additional scenarios, they need to be specified, designed, implemented, tested and supported - all of which takes time. So far, the scenario you describe: hasn't had that time invested.

It may be possible to configure the base-type properties using the `RuntimeTypeModel` API, but I must emphasize: whenever a question arises that is essentially:

> My existing model isn't working well with my chosen serializer

my default response (based on literally decades of experience in this field) is:

> If your existing model isn't a great fit for a different serializer: stop fighting the serializer. Instead, create a new model that works perfectly with your new choice of serializer, and shim between models at the point of (de)serialization

Comment: The scenario I'm talking about is quite a simple one: here is an object of class A, it needs no be serialized/deserialized. There is no other serializer I know of, which cannot do that because some of properties of (known) type A are inherited. So the reasons for assumptions and compromises are not clear.

It works, by the way. It's just needs [ProtoInclude] attribute for every subclass - or equivalent configuration in code. That is probably not a deal breaker.

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that the assumption made was it's needed to support all possible inheritance scenarios, with substitution principle etc.?

Comment: I'm saying: because it knows that inheritance is a thing, it currently has an implementation that works with inheritance which it does root-first for LSP reasons. Because of that, it doesn't look for properties in the base-type, because it assumes inheritance will be dealing with those. Right now, there are 3 options available: configure the type manually via RuntimTypeModel; formally tell it about the inheritance relationship; or accept that *right now*: that isn't a supported scenario (it potentially could become one, but it would require work)

Comment: I see, thanks!

BTW your response lead to indentifying another option - make base class properties abstract and implementing them in derived classes. I like this more than 100+ [ProtoInclude] attributes on base class, and compiler will care they are not omitted. So there will be no inherited properties for protobuf-net to take care of.